Call fsync on ZipArchive in PHP
Is there anyway to get access to underlying stream used by a ZipArchive in php so that fsync can be called on it?
I am looking to explicitly flush an archive I am creating to NFS to force propagation.

There's no public interface in the documentation. You could check the source code to see if there's an undocumented interface, but I doubt it. It may not write anything until you call close(), and by the time that returns the stream will be gone and there's nothing to call fsync on.
